# Dynamic paint waves: How do I change color of

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, dynamic-paint

I'm new to blender and love the dynamic paint waves function. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to change the color of a material based on movement of the ripples simulated on the canvas layer. sort of like a different color for peaks / valleys / original height(non moving surfaces).

I am not using a flat plane, so I don't think I can fake it with a gradient being projected from the side. I tried using a wetmap, but that doesn't give me the results I want. Maybe rendering a velocity pass could get me close but I'm not sure if it would look right.

Basically my end goal is to make all moving surfaces to be white and all non moving surfaces to be black. If possible, maybe even take it 1 step further to differentiate the peaks and valleys of the ripples. I uploaded an image to show my setup.

[image]